# CUDA: Unaligned Memory Access Not Supported: What am I missing?

Tags: python, cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

There are a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682481/why-do-i-have-an-unaligned-memory-accesses-not-supported-error) similar to this but in this case, its a bit weird; NVCC 3.1 doesn't like this but 3.2 and 4.0RC do;

```
float xtmp[MAT1];

for (i=0; i<MAT1; i++){
    xtmp[i]=x[p[i]]; //value that should be here
}
```

Where p is passed by reference to the function (int *p) coming from...

```
int p_pivot[MAT1],q_pivot[MAT1];
```

To add a bit of context, before the p's get to the 'top' function, they are populated by (I'm cutting out as much irrelevant code as i can for clarity)

```
...
for (i=0;i<MAT1;i++){
    ...
    p_pivot[i]=q_pivot[i]=i
    ...
}
...
```

Beyond that the only operations on pivot are 3-step-swaps with integer temporary values.

After all that p_pivot is passed to the 'top' function by (&p_pivot[0])

For anyone looking for more detail, the code is [here](http://pastebin.com/nq1yp8Fn) and the only change that should be needed to flip between 3.2/4.0 to earlier is to change the cudaDeviceSynchronise(); to cudaThreadSynchronize();. This is my dirty dirty experimental code so please don't judge me! :D

As noted, all of the above works fine in higher versions of NVCC, and I'm working to get those put onto the machine in question, but I'd be interested to see what I'm missing.

It must be the array-lookup indexing that's causing the issue, but I don't understand why?

Comment: So this is your forward and backward substitution routines, and p is the pivot vector? You might need to add a little more context to the code to understand what might be happening. I don't remember any compiler bugs in nvOpen64 from last year that might cause this, but you never know....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a compiler bug to me. This will work with nvcc 3.1 on 64 bit platforms:

```
float xtmp[MAT1];
//Swap rows (x=Px)
for (i=0; i<MAT1; i++){
    int idx = p[i];
    xtmp[i]=x[idx]; //value that should be here
}
```

My guess is that something in the implicit int to size_t conversion is breaking. Doesn't fail with any of the newer versions of CUDA I have tried.

Comment: Thats the fix i implemented but im intrigued as to when this was changed *digging through release notes now...*

Comment: You won't get the full manifest of changes from the the release notes. NVIDIA have a private bug tracking database for registered developers, and even there you can't see everyone else's bug reports. If you find a bug and report it, they will tell you when it is fixed. If someone else found it and reported it, you won't know. Which is a bit sucky, but I understand why they do it.

Comment: I've been registered for a few weeks and every time I search for something, no results, lol.